# Replacing every byte in a given directory with 0x00

Tags: macos, bash, sed, byte, erase

I am trying to create a function that can go in my `.bash_profile` file that will replace every byte in every file in a given directory with `0x00`. The program will loop through all of the files in a given directory which is `$(1)` (the *looping*), and in each file go through all of the bytes and replace them with `0x00` (the *replacing*).

I got the looping down, but I can't figure out how to do the replacing. Could you please help me? If I can get this function to work, I might distribute it as an effective way to erase data. Thank you so much for your help!

There was another post where someone wanted to replace one set of bytes with another. Mine is different, but maybe it would use the `sed` command, too.

Comment: Take a look: [How to install gshred](http://superuser.com/q/617515/340330)

Comment: You could use `dd` for things like this, but `shred` is already available.

Comment: @Cyrus gshred/shred didn't work, but it led me to srm. I am looking for something like this, but I want to 1) build it myself, and 2) keep the files and just replace everything with 0x00, which translates as spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dd`:

```
hd targetfile # optionally look at hex dump to see original file contents

SIZE=$(stat -f%z targetfile) # get file size
dd if=/dev/zero of=targetfile count=1 bs="$SIZE" # overwrite file contents

hd targetfile # optionally look at hex dump to see it's all zeros
```

Note, on Linux, the file size switch of *stat* would be `-c%s`, which I tested with. Above `-f%z` is based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185039/33724), and I didn't test it.

You might also want to add return value check for *stat* and verify that file size is greater than zero, before using *dd*. Something like:

```
SIZE=$(stat -f%z targetfile) &&
test "$SIZE" -gt 0 &&
dd if=/dev/zero of=targetfile count=1 bs="$SIZE"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s/./\x00/g;" file # sets any char to 0 except returns
```

anyway similar ways may create file of the same name, with the same size filled with zeroes, but it is not sure, if such files would occupy the same space on the disc as originals, so the bytes of originals may be possible find later in "free space between files"

the right way would use something more sophisticated, either specialized tools for rewriting content of sector or at least program which open file in binary mode and overwrite each byte with zero.

Still there could be those "secret bytes" hidden somewhere on disc, if those files was somehow manipulated before (edited, copied, ...) so to get rid of "evidence", you also need to rewrite all "unoccupied space" on disc

And hope, that some remaping of sectors had happened (as HDDs can map-out defective sectors automatically and those can be later recovered and SSDs do some dirty tricks with wear-leveling and remapping sectors too)

So you still need to consider the price and the risk. Good old termite is silver bullet here :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change all files behind some directory, `find` + `dd` are the way to go. The following script should do the trick.

**Note:** on Darwin (OSX) you need to change from `stat -c%s` to `stat -f%z` as already pointed out by hyde.

```
#!/bin/bash
[ ! -d "$1" ] && echo "Usage: $0 <directory>" && exit 1
find "$1" -type f ! -empty | while read f; do
  dd if=/dev/zero of="$f" count=1 bs=`stat -c%s "$f"` > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo "$f failed"
done
```